# cannot apply operator * to operands int and Task<int>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have an asnyc method to return an integer (thus, `async Task<int>`) and I need to multiply the return value by another method that returns just `int`. As this does not work, how can I convert `async Task<int>` to `int`? Is it `Convert.ToInt32(AsyncMethod())`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use await before async method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method does not *return* an `int` but a `Task` that has a result type of `int`. And this task is or may be still running when your method returns.

So you'll have to wait for that task to complete. You have (at least) two options to do that:

1. If the calling method is an `async` method (or can be declared as `async`), you can use the `await` keyword:

   ```
   public async Task CallingMethod()
   {
       int result = await YourMethod();
       // do what you want the result
   }
   ```

   This will convert the `CallingMethod` into a *state machine* . The control flow will be returned to the caller while the `Task` is running and execution will be resumed after the `await` (assigning the result to `result`) when the `Task` completed.
2. You can use the `Result` property of the returned `Task<int>`:

   ```
   public void CallingMethod()
   {
       int result = YourMethod().Result;
       // do what you want the result
   }
   ```

   This will block execution and wait until the `Task` has completed and then assign the resulting `int` to `result`.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, as well as for the good explanation! Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `await` keyword will automatically unwrap a `Task<T>` into `T`.

For example:

```
async void Test()
{
    Task<int> b = GetNumberAsync();
    int c = await GetNumberAsync();
}
```

Note that this means your method must be marked `async` as well. Or, you can run the task to full completion, and extract the value via `.Result`

Comment: You cannot mark Main as async, might want to change that function name.

Comment: @bodangly You're right, thanks - I've edited :)